# AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQualityWithAlpha decreases quality when exporting video

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I need to import a video, process and then export the video with alpha. I noticed the video gets a lot grayer/loses quality compared to the original. I don't need any compression.

*Sidenote: I need to export video's with transparency enabled, that's why I use `AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQualityWithAlpha`. It seems that that is causing the problem, since `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` is looking good.*

This are side-by-side frames of the original and a video that's processed. The left is the original frame, the right is a processed video.

[image]

This is another example where the bottom is exported and the above is the original. You can see at the bar where the YouTube NL is displayed, that the above one is almost fully black, while the below one (exported) is really gray:

[image]

As far as I know, I don't do anything special, I just load the video and directly export it. It still loses quality. How can I prevent this?

**Reproduction path**

You can either clone the repository, or see the code below.

The repository is available here: https://github.com/Jasperav/VideoCompression/tree/main/VideoCompressionTests. After you cloned it, run the only unit-test and check the logging of where the output of the video is stored. You can then observe that temp.mov is a lot grayer than the original video.

The code of importing and exporting the video is here. As far as I can see, I just import and directly export the movie without modifying it. What's the problem?

```
import AppKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import Photos
import QuartzCore
import OSLog

let logger = Logger()

class VideoEditor {
    func export(
        url: URL,
        outputDir: URL
    ) async {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let extract = try! await extractData(videoAsset: asset)
    
        try! await exportVideo(outputPath: outputDir, asset: asset, videoComposition: extract)
    }

    private func exportVideo(outputPath: URL, asset: AVAsset, videoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition) async throws {
        let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputPath.path())

        logger.debug("Output dir: \(outputPath), exists: \(fileExists), render size: \(String(describing: videoComposition.renderSize))")

        if fileExists {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: outputPath.path())
            } catch {
                logger.error("remove file failed")
            }
        }

        let dir = outputPath.deletingLastPathComponent().path()

        logger.debug("Will try to create dir: \(dir)")

        try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true)

        var isDirectory = ObjCBool(false)

        guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dir, isDirectory: &isDirectory), isDirectory.boolValue else {
            logger.error("Could not create dir, or dir is a file")

            fatalError()
        }

        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQualityWithAlpha) else {
            logger.error("generate export failed")

            fatalError()
        }

        exporter.outputURL = outputPath
        exporter.outputFileType = .mov
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
        exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition

        await exporter.export()

        logger.debug("Status: \(String(describing: exporter.status)), error: \(exporter.error)")

        if exporter.status != .completed {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    private func extractData(videoAsset: AVURLAsset) async throws -> AVMutableVideoComposition {
        guard let videoTrack = try await videoAsset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
            fatalError()
        }

        let composition = AVMutableComposition(urlAssetInitializationOptions: nil)

        guard let compositionVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: videoTrack.trackID) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        let duration = try await videoAsset.load(.duration)

        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: duration), of: videoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)

        let naturalSize = try await videoTrack.load(.naturalSize)
        let preferredTransform = try await videoTrack.load(.preferredTransform)
        let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, end: duration)

        let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        let frameRate = try await videoTrack.load(.nominalFrameRate)
 
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(frameRate))

        mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
        videoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        
        videoComposition.renderSize = naturalSize

        return videoComposition
    }

}
```

Comment: If you compress the same file many times you must loose quality, that can’t be avoided. I assume the exported file gets smaller and smaller each time?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes the files decreases about 200KB each time (from 50 MB). I can understand it gets smaller every time because of the compression, but I still think it's strange. I mean if I would zip a file and zip the zip a few times, it also doesn't loose content in the end and the files would be the same size. I was hoping to accomplish that as well.

Comment: I am also doing only 3 import and exports. On screen recordings, it looks awfully gray. I would suspect that after 3 exports it wouldn't look as bad as it looks now.

Comment: Actually on the very first export it already starts looking gray, way more than expected.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I updated the repository with a new screen recording video where it's already very clear after 1 export, it's lost a lot of quality. The black pixels gets gray really quick.

Comment: @J.Doe - rendering a video is a ***lossy*** process. ZIP is a ***lossless*** process. You will always lose quality when re-rendering a video.

Comment: @DonMag Fair enough. But don't you agree the output of the processed video is now too gray?

Comment: @J.Doe -- hmmm... here is what I get, screen-capped from zoomed-in using QuickTime Player... I added the light-blue label after capture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xECFo.png - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrBAQ.png - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIDI9.png ... I see very little difference?

Comment: @J.Doe - yes... multiple exports absolutely will degrade the quality. Always start with the original video.

Comment: @DonMag I noticed a big difference between VLC and QuickTime player: https://imgur.com/a/cygfqjs. I always used VLC, but it shows the video much grayer than QuickTime. It was until your comment I thought that it was the problem of the movie file itself, but it's VLC. For now, I will try to process the video in one go, instead of importing and exporting multiple times and use QuickTime. Thanks!